# To display the title for the current loaction in map in iphone

Tags: iphone, dictionary, title

I am new to iphone development. I have created map applications and i displayed the cuurent locations and drop a pin to the current location. now i want to display the title and subtitle of the current location when i am clicking the pin. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display title and subtitle your annotation object you add to map must respond to `-title` and `-subTitle` messages (defined in `MKAnnotation` protocol as optional).

**Edit:** You can also obtain information about given location  using `MKReverseGeocoder` class that queries google based servises for that and returns data via its delegate (see `MKReverseGeocoderDelegate` protocol).

Comment: i have already used MKAnnotation protocol and i have disaplyed the title statically. I want to display the title dynamically when i am find the current location at any place.