# How to Automatically Display Title/Subtitle on Map Annotation (pin)

Tags: iphone, dictionary, annotations

I am loading an annotation onto my map view. The annotation displays as a pin when the map is loaded.

However, the title and subtitle do not appear on the pin automatically. Currently, the user is required to tap on the pin before the title displays.

Is there a way to get the title to display automatically on the pin when the map is loaded?

(This question is almost the same thing, but not quite there: [To display the title for the current loaction in map in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355413/to-display-the-title-for-the-current-loaction-in-map-in-iphone) because I already have the -title and -subtitle attributes defined in my object.)

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method to call is "selectAnnotation:animated" from MKMapView.

Answer (score 9):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{    
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate] ,350,350);

    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];    

    [mapView selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];

}
```

if you are doing the same thing which is  calling the setRegion method, then make sure that you call

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:mp animated:YES];
```

after

```
[mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in iOS 11, there is a new type of `MKAnnotationView` called `MKMarkerAnnotationView`, which can display title and subtitle without being selected. Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmarkerannotationview

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
        return nil
    }

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        let annoView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "HunterAnno")
        annoView.canShowCallout = true
        return annoView
    }

    let annoView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "HunterAnnoLow")
    annoView.canShowCallout = true
    return annoView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a follow-up answer (that is applicable to Xcode 11.4 and Swift 5), as I had this exact problem, but the above answers did not work. @zsani is correct in that you need to use `MKMarkerAnnotationView` (as opposed to `MKPinAnnotationView`) to get both, but you also have to set the `titleVisibility` and `subtitleVisibility` properties (although `titleVisibility` seems to be on by default with `MKMarkerAnnotationView`).

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    // do not alter user location marker
    guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else { return nil }

    // get existing marker
    var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier") as? MKMarkerAnnotationView

    // is this a new marker (i.e. nil)?
    if view == nil {
        view = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: nil, reuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier")
    }

    // set subtitle to show without being selected
    view?.subtitleVisibility = .visible

    // just for fun, show green markers where subtitles exist; red otherwise
    if let _ = annotation.subtitle! {
        view?.markerTintColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        view?.markerTintColor = UIColor.red
    }

    return view
}
```

Sharing in case anyone else has this same problem.