# MKAnnotation showing issues

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I created MKMapView with a pin on it.

When I press a pin, I see the title and subtitle, but I want to see it without tapping.
So, I want title and subtitle to appear immediately after showing of map.

Here is my code:

```
    self.mapView = [[[MKMapView alloc]init] autorelease];
    mapView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

    location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lattitude, longitude);



    MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
    region.center = location;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = kSpan;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = kSpan;
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    CustomMapAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[CustomMapAnnotation alloc] init];
    newAnnotation.title = @"Title";
    newAnnotation.subtitle = @"Subtitle";
    newAnnotation.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitButton;

    newAnnotation.coordinate = location;
    annotation = newAnnotation;
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [newAnnotation release];

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotationDel
{

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;

    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"mapPin";

    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

    if (pinView == nil)
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotationDel reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    [pinView setSelected:YES];

    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(detailButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return pinView;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to call viewForAnnotation in the viewdidload method? After the pin appears?

Comment: Patel answered correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `MKMapView's` `selectAnnotation:animated` method

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:YorAnnotation animated:YES];
```

For More info read [How to trigger MKAnnotationView's callout view without touching the pin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978897/how-to-trigger-mkannotationviews-callout-view-without-touching-the-pin) and [How to Automatically Display Title/Subtitle on Map Annotation (pin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663563/how-to-automatically-display-title-subtitle-on-map-annotation-pin) Question.