# How to display user current location name or address on annotation or pin in iOS?

Tags: ios, maps

Is it possible to have the users current locations Name or address on the annotation or on the pin automatically?

Comment: Please check this link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html

Comment: Please check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663563/how-to-automatically-display-title-subtitle-on-map-annotation-pin